# Showing specific content for anonymous users with Thymeleaf Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm struggling with the following. I have a nav-bar and i want to show/hide specific content depending on whether the user is anonymous/role_user/role_admin. Here is my html:

```
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org xmlns:sec="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Beer Tag Home</title>

    </head>
    <body>

    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" id="mainNav">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Foo App</a> 

            <div class="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a About</li>
                    <li class="nav-item">FAQ</li>


                     <div class="row" th:if="not${#authentication.isAuthenticated()}">
//this here will not even let spring boot up the app
                    <li class="nav-item">LOGIN</li>
                </div>

<div class="row" <div th:if="${#httpServletRequest.isUserInRole('ROLE_USER')}">
                    <li class="nav-item">USER PANEL</li>
                </div>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Essentially I want to see if a user is Anonymous if so he can only log in. If a user is logged in he can access other content on the page. Here are my gradle dependencies as well:

compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

```
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf', version: '3.0.11.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4', version: '3.0.4.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
```

I've read almost all posts on SO regarding this subject, but none of them gives a definitive answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display a block for anonymous only:

```xml
<div th:if="!${#request.userPrincipal}">
  <!-- content for anonymous -->
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a nice thymeleaf extras module: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity

After adding it you can use it like this:

```
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
  This content is only shown to authenticated users.
</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
  This content is only shown to administrators.
</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
  This content is only shown to users.
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried to. Does not seem to recognize the sec:authorize attribute and just shows all. Thank you though!